# Python 3 markdown to html: how to enable code-fencing / syntax highlighting

Tags: python, markdown

I'm trying to programatically generate html from .md source files.

If I edit them in the `Remarkable` editor, which uses python3 markdown it works. By which I mean html exported from the editor is correct. For example the source

```
~~~~python
import os, sys
~~~~
```

yields html which is approximately rendered as

```py
import os, sys
```

However, when my python script tries to render the text this syntax appears not to be supported. The fencing tags just appear in the output instead of being parsed. I basically do this:

```py
html = markdown.markdown(md_text)
```

Python appears not to recognise the fenced_code extension:

```
>>> markdown.markdown (markdown_text, extensions=markdown.extensions.fenced_code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'markdown.extensions' has no attribute 'fenced_code'
>>> dir (markdown.extensions)
['Extension', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'parseBoolValue', 'unicode_literals', 'warnings']
```

I assume the relevant extension must be there since `Remarkable` is processing the code correctly.

***How do I enable code fencing / syntax highlighting?***

Github-style fencing is the same, ie it works in remarkable and not in my script. Block indenting just seems to do block-quote highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error you're getting...

```
AttributeError: module 'markdown.extensions' has no attribute 'fenced_code'
```

...is because you haven't imported `markdown.extensions.fenced_code`:

```
>>> import markdown.extensions.fenced_code
```

But then you have a second problem, which is that the `extensions` keyword takes a list:

```
>>> markdown.markdown (markdown_text, extensions=markdown.extensions.fenced_code)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

But actually, the `markdown.markdown` method isn't expecting a module:

```
>>> markdown.markdown (markdown_text, extensions=[markdown.extensions.fenced_code])
TypeError: Extension "builtins.module" must be of type: "markdown.Extension"
```

You can do what the error says and pass in a class instance, or you can just pass in the extension name as a string and let `markdown` figure it out:

```
>>> markdown.markdown (markdown_text, extensions=['fenced_code'])
```

Hopefully it's obvious, but using this model you don't need to import `markdown.extensions.fenced_code` either using this mechanism, because you're never using the module name.  That is, this is a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import markdown

markdown_text = '''# This is a test

~~~~python
import os, sys
~~~~
'''

print(markdown.markdown(markdown_text,
                        extensions=['fenced_code', 'codehilite']))
```

Note that code highlighting is provided by a the `codehilite` extension, which will only work if you also have the `pygments` library installed.

Comment: thanks. Also pygments.css was all geared around the css class being called `.highlight` I had to change it to `.codehilite`